# Solving a nasty system functional equation, with the functions having 2 variables

Tags: python, numpy, physics, equation

I am trying to model a basketball 3 point shot. Taking into account different forces I have equations for the ball's position and velocity. My goal is to find the different combination of initial velocities v0 = (v0x, v0y, v0z) and angular spin omega0x which maximise the chances of scoring a 3 point shot.

My strategy is to numerically solve the velocity equations at the time t = 1s  holding all variables constant except the initial velocity and spin. I my initial velocities and spin be an arrays containing different values. Once I have values for the velocity at time t=1 for the different values of v0 and omega0, I will plug them into the equation for position to then get different values for the final x,y and z coordinates based on different velocities and spins.

My equations are like this:

```
#velocity vector components
vx = v0x + F_m*t /m - F_d/m * vx/(np.sqrt(vx**2 +vy**2 +vz**2)) *t 
vy = v0y - F_d*t/m * vy/(np.sqrt(vx**2 +vy**2 +vz**2)) *t 
vz = v0z - F_d*t/m * vz/(np.sqrt(vx**2 +vy**2 +vz**2)) *t 

#Position vector components
x= v0x*t + F_m *t**2 /(2*m) - F_d*t**2/(2*m)*vx/(np.sqrt(vx**2 +vy**2 +vz**2))
y= v0y*t + F_m *t**2 /(2*m) - F_d*t**2/(2*m)*vy/(np.sqrt(vx**2 +vy**2 +vz**2))
z= v0z*t + F_m *t**2 /(2*m) - F_d*t**2/(2*m)*vz/(np.sqrt(vx**2 +vy**2 +vz**2))

t = 1 
v0x = np.arange()
v0y = np.arange()
v0z = np.arange()
omega = np.arange()
m = 
F_d = 
F_m =
```

The problem is this equation looks nasty and I don't know of any method in Python which allows me to solve this. Also, there are so many different combinations of v0x, v0y, v0z and omega to try.
Any help would be great.

Comment: Are you sure your equations are correct? (I'm asking because `omega` does not appear in them). Otherwise `scipy.integrate.OdeSolver` is always a great tool for these kinds of problem.

Comment: Hi thanks for asking. Omega is the angular velocity. For simplification purposes, I have decided it is constant and only acts in the x direction. It is a part of the Magnus force F_m.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [scipy.integrate.OdeSolver](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.OdeSolver.html) is the way to go. Your equations will need some significant rewriting though. Basically, you need to find a way to rewrite your equations in the form `dy/dt = f(y, t)` (in your case, `y` would be `[vx, vy, vz, x, y , z]`. This is a standard technique in physics that you'll find in any physics textbook, so if you're not familiar with that, I'd suggest starting from there. Once you've found `f`, you can just feed it to `scipy`'s ODE solver and get the trajectory of the ball.

As for the initial parameters, I'm afraid there is no good general solution here, it really depends on the system you're studying, so I'd start by just brute-forcing a few thousands initial conditions and see what kind of result you get.